# ACL - remove any implicit permissions

Tags: ubuntu, acl

How to remove all implicit permissions for a group for a directory? Lets say for a group named "A" we have specified permissions now if I remove a user from group "A", will this user still have the same permissions or will it have some kind of default fallback permissions? I want to ensure that a user removed from a group will automatically won't have any permissions to a directory it earlier had.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove standards rights you can use  (will remove standard rights rwx for the group :

```
chmod g-rwx *
```

You can add -R if you want it recursive in this case (will do the same all over files even inside sub-directories.

```
chmod -R g-rwx *
```

If there is specific rights such a sticky bit on the files the you should also run

```
chmod -R g-s *
```